# Using static libraries on a C project in XCode 4.5.2

Tags: c, xcode, file, static

I'm new to Xcode so not really keen on it yet. In my college is used visual studio to program in C in which they create a solution and fill it with an application and then include static libraries with .h and .c files. Been trying to do this in Xcode but can't seem to include them or add dependencies like in Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

One approach is just using the standard gcc command line options for static library linking which you can specify using the XCode project settings.  This will work if the static library is installed and accessible in the standard locations.

Alternatively you can add a static library explicitly to your project and set the dependencies and search paths for headers etc appropriately.  This may sound a bit involved, but there's not really that much to do, and you only need to set it up once.  It's all done in the same place as other project settings, and you can use the search box to find exactly where to enter the options.

I'm assuming you don't want to actually build the static library with your project.  if you do there's more to do - basically you need to set up the static library project, set it as a target dependency, and setup a build step to copy the resulting library.